# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object when passing object to a class

Tags: php, laravel

I have a route in my controller:

```
$emailRecipient = DB::select("
            select 
                e.ID empID,
                e.lname lname,
                e.fname fname,
                e.email email,
                e.teamID,
                e.agencyID,
                e.accessProfileID, 
                e.accessTeams,
                c.ID coID,
                c.dDesc companyName
                c.product,
                c.modules
            from 
                emailrecipient_tb er
                    left join employee_tb e on er.empID = e.ID
                    left join company_tb c on er.coID = c.ID
            where 
                er.isDAR = 1 and 
                er.isActive = 1 and
                c.isActive = 1
        ");

        foreach ($emailRecipient as $rowRecipient) {
            Mail::to($rowRecipient->email)->send(new DailyActivityReport2($rowRecipient));
        }
```

and then in my DailyActivityReport2 class I have:

```
    public $coID;
    public $companyName;
    public $product;
    public $rEmpID;
    public $rLname;
    public $rFname;
    public $rEmail;
    public $rAccessTeamID;
    public $rAccessAgencyID;
    public $rAccessProfileID;
    public $rAccessTeams;
    public $rModules;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($rowRecipient)
    {
        $coID = $rowRecipient->coID;
        $companyName = $rowRecipient->companyName;
        $product = $rowRecipient->product;
        $rEmpID = $rowRecipient->empID;
        $rLname = $rowRecipient->lname;
        $rFname = $rowRecipient->fname;
        $rEmail = $rowRecipient->email;
        $rAccessTeamID = $rowRecipient->teamID;
        $rAccessAgencyID = $rowRecipient->agencyID;
        $rAccessProfileID = $rowRecipient->accessProfileID;
        $rAccessTeams = $rowRecipient->accessTeams;
        $rModules = json_decode($rowRecipient->modules);
    }
```

then I get an error:

```
Trying to get property 'coID' of non-object
```

the error is at:

```
$coID = $rowRecipient->coID;
```

The thing is if I try to use $rowRecipient->coID in the controller then the code works, only when I pass it in the class, then it no longer works...

Comment: Can you do `dd($emailRecipient);` before foreach? What do you get? I guess you have problem with your query...

Comment: You are using the DB facade, so it will not be an object, but an array. I also think you need db raw, not select since you are passing a full query string.

Comment: change this $rowRecipient->coID to $rowRecipient['coID']

Comment: @GertB. unless they are using a very very old version of Laravel `select` is returning an array of `stdClass` objects (and they are iterating the array), and the `select` method is for raw queries as this is not Query Builder

Comment: side note: what is the point of assigning all of those temporary variables in the constructor?

Comment: @lagbox I think that is an other mistake, and it needs to be `$this->coID` . And I try to forget about the very old Laravel versions, that are not supported anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm stupid, I didn't realize I hard-coded coID in the controller (for testing).